# Adding up two Time fields in mysql returns null

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Why does this work:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('08:00:00' as time) + CAST('06:00:00' as time) as time);
result: 14
```

And not with these other values?

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('08:30:00' as time) + CAST('06:30:00' as time) as time);
result: NULL
```

Comment: your first query returns January, 01 1970 14:00:00+0000 for me

Comment: To debug 'stuff', i suggest you select all the 'components' as separate columns to ensure that you get sensible results. Then start combining them and check that they return what you expect. You may need to look at the 'AddTime' function as the '+' operator does not appear to apply to times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ADDTIME:

```
SELECT ADDTIME(CAST('08:30:00' as TIME), CAST('06:30:00' as TIME));
```

Answer (score 2):

because you're adding times in an arithmetic context:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select cast('08:30:00' as time), cast('06:30:00' as time);
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| cast('08:30:00' as time) | cast('06:30:00' as time) |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| 08:30:00                 | 06:30:00                 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select cast('08:30:00' as time) + cast('06:30:00' as time);
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| cast('08:30:00' as time) + cast('06:30:00' as time) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                              146000 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+

MariaDB [(none)]> select cast(146000 as time);
+----------------------+
| cast(146000 as time) |
+----------------------+
| NULL                 |
+----------------------+
```

You cannot add times together like that. Try this instead:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select cast('08:30:00' as time) + INTERVAL 6 HOUR + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| cast('08:30:00' as time) + INTERVAL 6 HOUR + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 15:00:00                                                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

to do this you have to convert the time. basically its trying to convert 14:60:00 to time 146000.. but that would be 15:00:00 and thats why it returns null. if you do a conversion then it will perform properly.

```
SELECT 
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        TIME_TO_SEC(CAST('08:30:00' as time)) 
      + TIME_TO_SEC(CAST('06:30:00' as time))
    )
```